# Небольшое приложение с использованием 3D. На чем писать и с чего начать

Tags: javascript, java, 3d

Всем привет. Появилась необходимость создания небольшого приложения с использованием 3D, в котором можно было бы управлять сборкой как с помощью панели управления, так и с помощью наглядного изображения (выделение деталей для задания её свойств). 
Поскольку в 3D новичок, подскажите в чем будет проще выполнить поставленную задачу: думал о приложении на Java, хотя потом подсказали попробовать сделать для браузера с помощью javascript (Three.js), тем более что опыт работы с js есть. 
Так же буду рад похожим примерам.

Answer (score 1):

Может, во Flash окунуться - у него [неплохие возможности в 3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html). ActionScript похож на Java и JavaScript синтаксисом.

Ещё вариант с Java-подобным языком — [Processing](http://www.processing.org/). Скачайте, погоняйте примеры. Он импортирует распостранённые 3Д форматы моделей.